# Toggle between menu buttons and toggle button

Tags: angularjs

I have a navigation component in which the active element gains a different color. But also the active element should be able to be toggled on/off.

So I created a function for each navigation element that sets it's "own" navigation element to true (or false) and all the other values to false:

```
public toggleHomeX() {
    if (this.toggleHome) {
        this.toggleHome = !this.toggleHome;
    } else {
        this.toggleHome = !this.toggleHome;
        this.toggleContact = false;
        this.toggleAbout = false;
        this.toggleOther = false;
    }
}

public toggleContactX() {
    if (this.toggleContact) {
        this.toggleContact = !this.toggleContact;
    } else {
        this.toggleContact = !this.toggleContact;
        this.toggleHome = false;
        this.toggleOther = false;
        this.toggleAbout = false;
    }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/LURJUXhAudSdQnMdzcOo?p=preview

This of course works, but it makes for some horrible code. How could I abstract the functions so I can simplify this code?

Comment: you can reset them all to `false` in a common function, and then set the relevant one to `true` in their personal function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, you only need define one function and one variable and the code will be more clear.

```
this.toggleValue = "";
public toggleX(value) {
      this.toggleValue = value;
```

[jsfiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/hifgCn9SgITSoFIo348i?p=preview)

Comment: Now you can't toggle the active menu.